# Access 2010 update query based on a conversion table

Tags: ms-access, sql-update, ms-access-2010

Is there any way that I can, in a single statemente, update the contents of a table based on a conversion table?

For example, if I have the following table called MyStuff

```
Key | Values
----+-------
  1 | Apples
  2 | Oranges
  3 | Bananas
```

And supose I have the following ConversionTable

```
Old Key | New Key
--------+--------
      1 | 101
      2 | 202
      3 | 303
```

What I'm looking for is an update SQL statement that, based on ConversionTable, would produce the following changes in MyStuff

```
Key | Values
----+-------
101 | Apples
202 | Oranges
303 | Bananas
```

Comment: If Key in MyStuff is an autonumber, no, you cannot do this. If it is a number, you can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming A.[Key] is not an autonumber, this should work:

```
Update MyStuff A
INNER JOIN Conversion B
on A.Key = B.[Old Key]
Set A.[Key] = B.[New Key]
```

Comment: Indeed, but I reckon INNER JOIN would be safer.

Comment: Why would you think so?

Comment: Add row 4 in MyStuff with no match in Conversion, with LEFT JOIN you will get a message that you are about to update 4 rows, with INNER JOIN, the message is, correctly, 3 rows. Furthermore, the missing conversion row is changed to Null with LEFT JOIN.

Comment: Yeah, at first I didn't think it mattered but you're probably right.  Never overestimate the intelligence of the End User.  :oP  I'll make that change.  Thanks for pointing it out.